# MSSQL with SSL: The target principal name is incorrect

Tags: sql-server, ssl

I configured successfully SSL on Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express Edition for the purpose of encrypting external network connections to the database that are made through Internet. For performance reasons for internal clients on the network I do not want to force the use of SSL and leave to the clients the option of use it or not. I set **Force Encryption** to **No** with the following steps:

- **Sql Server Configuration Manager**
- **Sql Server Network Configuration**
- **Protocols for (MYSQLSERVERNAME)**
- Right click: **Properties**
- **Flags** tab.

When I try to establish an encrypted connection with Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio checking **Encrypt connection** option on **Options** > **Connection Properties** I get the following error.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893022)

What is striking is that if I select **Force Encryption** as **Yes** on Sql Server Configuration Manager and I not select **Encrypt connection** on Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio I can connect to the database. If I execute the query:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

In fact the column **encrypt_option** is TRUE.

The certificate was generated with Openssl and this is the information:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 2 (0x2)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun  9 15:53:18 2016 GMT
            Not After : Jun  9 15:53:18 2018 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=State, L=Location, O=Testing, OU=Development, CN=JOSEPH-ASUS
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                ...
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                DB:7F:58:DC:F7:D9:90:2A:DF:0E:31:84:5C:49:68:E7:61:97:D8:41
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:C9:5C:79:34:E0:83:B2:C7:26:21:90:17:6A:86:88:84:95:19:88:EA

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            Netscape Comment: 
                OpenSSL Generated Certificate
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:alternatename1, DNS:alternatename2, IP Address:192.168.1.100, IP Address:192.191.1.101, IP Address:192.168.1.103
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         ...
```

The current OS is Windows 10 Home.

What I'm missing?

Comment: I have this problem as well. Similar situation. Certificate created in OpenSSL (perhaps incorrectly). Differences: SQL Server 2014 Developer edition,  Windows 7.

Comment: Incidentally the differences between 'force encryption' on server and 'force encryption' on client and 'encrypt connection' in SSMS are described here:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bde679d9-ff83-4fa7-b402-42e336a97106/force-encryption-on-sql-server-not-working?forum=sqlsecurity

Comment: @MeadowlarkBradsher that link was perfect in explaining what's happening - thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The certificate generated with OpenSSL work properly. In my case the problem was rights of the account under which runs MSSQL over the certificate, I solved this issue with the follow steps:

- Open **SQL Server Configuration Manager**.
- Locate the account which is used to run MSSQL instance (**Log On** tab on MSSQL instance **Properties**).
- Open **MMC** Console and add **Certificates** (Local Machine) snap-in.
- Search the certificate store, right click on certificate and select **All Tasks** -> **Manage Private Keys...**.
- Set the **Permissions** to the same account under which MSSSQL runs.

Comment: This was my case installed SQL 2016 Enterprise with the default "MSSQLSERVER" account, which is a "virtual account". In my case, I had to add the account "NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER" by typing it in (Windows won't find it if you search). Here is a long and detailed discussion on account permissions for SQL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?view=sql-server-2017#Serv_Perm

Comment: `Search the certificate store, right click on certificate and select All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys....` what does it mean? Which `certificate store`, there are thousands of certificates with them folders in MMC.

Answer (score 45):

I had the same issue and got resolved by adding `TrustServerCertificate=True;` to the connection string.

Comment: That is generally not considered safe to do in production.

Comment: Upvoted, although it could be improved; sometimes you just need stuff to work first. And this did work for me per https://productsupport.red-gate.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014370757-The-target-principal-name-is-incorrect

Comment: @MeadowlarkBradsher: Could you maybe give some background on that comment, because basically although I am using this workaround in dev/test, and don't need it in prod, background would really help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Shumachine When you set TrustServerCertificate=True you are saying that even if things don't match with you you will accept the connection. It is like someone checking to see if your signature on a check matches your signature on a license, seeing they don't match at all, and then cashing the check for you anyway. Trust in this case arises from [asymmetrical cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) where only the person with the private key can encrypt a secret. This gives everyone with a certificate (public key) an ability to verify the encrypter (signer).

Comment: "When TrustServerCertificate is set to true, the transport layer will use SSL to encrypt the channel and bypass walking the certificate chain to validate trust. If TrustServerCertificate is set to true and encryption is turned on, the encryption level specified on the server will be used even if Encrypt is set to false. The connection will fail otherwise."

Answer (score 17):

I received this error when I was doing something similar. I also created a certificate from OpenSSL and imported it into SQL Server. I also used SQL Server Management Studio to attempt to verify that the client side copy of the certificate was required. When I did this I got the error described above.

The solution was simply that in the window to connect I was not using the CN that is on the certificate:

[image]

Instead of 127.0.0.1 (or whatever you have there) put the CN on the certificate and this connection should work.

Comment: grateful for your time, do you suggest me the use of IP address instead of Common Name?, because I set the alternate IP on certificate.

Comment: What you want is for the the CN on the certificate to match the address you use to connect to the server. You can do that by changing the certificate, by changing the connection address, or both.

Comment: Interestingly for me, the common name (CN) wasn't the server name I needed to use. But instead the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) which was in the Subject Alternative Names attribute.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when trying to connect via [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017) to a server which required windows integrated authentication (option `-E`) but accidentally used Azure Active Directory Authentication (option `-G`).  Selecting the correct flags fixed it for me.   Note that this is the equivalent of including `Trusted_Connection=True` in the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your Server Certificate is using a *.domain name.

Make sure your SQL server has a certificate with a fully qualified name (sqlserver.yourcompany.com, not just *.yourcompany.com)

I used to get this same error when I had a *.mycompany.com certificate installed, but when I tried with a self-signed certificate specifically made for that SQL server, Then everything worked.

The steps are as follows:
Assuming you have already generated a certificate and it's in your machine

1. In certificate manager find your certificate, right click, all tasks, manage public keys, Allow the SQL server user (usually NT service\MSSQLSERVER) access to the private keys.
2. From certificate manager, export the cert without private keys and import them into a client machine
3. Open SQL server configuration manager > network > protocols > right click > certificate, select the new certificate. apply
4. Restart the SQL server instance

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in my case the problem with SQL Server 2019. I just changed to SQL Server 2018 version and tried it worked
[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Your image didn't come through. Please [edit] your question to correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the IP address instead of the server name then you need to add the server name to your user name like this:

```
your_username@your_servername
```

Answer (score 0):

I was scratching my head on this one for a while.

Setting `TrustServerCertificate=True` or `Encrypt=False` should not be done in production, so I had to make mine work without these flags.

What was confusing to me was that my SQL server *was* returning a valid certificate. You can check this via:

```bash
nmap -sV -p 1433 -Pn -vv --script ssl-cert <SQL-SERVER>
```

It turns out I made a silly mistake - updating your connection string in `appsettings.json` (or `appsettings.Development.json`) is not sufficient, you also need to make sure to update it in your DbContext `OnConfiguring` function:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder 
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(/*UPDATED CONNECTION STRING*/);
```

Or even better, make `OnConfiguring` read directly from your `appsettings.json` connection string.

Silly mistake, but they have to match, otherwise you get this rather confusing error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Sql Server Configuration Manager
2. Select SQL Server Network
3. Configuration -> Select Protocol for SQL Express

then check **Named Pipes** enabled.
and also **TCP/IP** should be enabled.

[Please check in below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4sW5.png)