# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.The target principal name is incorrect

Tags: c#, ssl, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2, kerberos

I created three certificate by using openssl

1. Root CA certificate
2. Server certificate
3. Client certificate

Server side configuration :

I installed server.cer(peronal folder) and RootCA(trust root certification authority folder) on server machine.Then i attached the server certificate 
to MSSSQL(SQL Configuration manager->MSSQL properties->certificate dropdown). Made the **Force Encryption to No** and restarted the service.

Client side configuration:

I installed client.cer(peronal folder) and RootCA(trust root certification authority folder).

Below are the steps to create RootCA(CertAuthority) and server.cert and client.crt :

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out CertAuthority.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key CertAuthority.key -out CertAuthority.crt
openssl req -new -sha256 -key CertAuthority.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in server.csr -CA CertAuthority.crt -CAkey CertAuthority.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt
openssl req -new -sha256 -key CertAuthority.key -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in client.csr -CA CertAuthority.crt -CAkey CertAuthority.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt
```

Details given at the time of CertAuthority.crt creation

```
Common Name : asia.com
Country : IN
```

remaining fields are left blank

Details given at the time of server.crt creation

```
Common Name : Myserver.asia.com
Country : IN
```

remaining fields are left blank

Details given at the time of Client.crt creation

```
Common Name : Myclient.asia.com
Country : IN
```

remaining fields are left blank

Here is the connection string i am using for sqlclient

```
Data Source=Myserver;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=sa;Password=;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False
```

Whenever i am trying to connect via SQLOLEDB provider by using "**Use Encryption For Data=True**" as an alternate of **Encrypt and TrustServerCertificate** property, I am able to establish SSL connection successfully.

But by using SqlConnection i am getting following error:
**A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.)**

Can somebody help me out in this regard. Thanks

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734311/mssql-with-ssl-the-target-principal-name-is-incorrect

Comment: I already tried this and didn't work

Comment: [The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/meer_alam/2015/05/10/the-target-principal-name-is-incorrect-cannot-generate-sspi-context/) on MSDN. It takes you through the troubleshooting steps.

Comment: *"`Common Name : Myserver.asia.com` ... remaining fields are left blank"* is probably wrong. Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) It provides a lot of background information on X.509 server certificates, and where the various rules come from.

Comment: *`Common Name : Myclient.asia.com`* may be wrong. Also see [Step-by-Step Guide to Mapping Certificates to User Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742438.aspx) on MSDN. Microsoft uses special sauce for identifying principals (UPNs) in client certificates.

Comment: Review the SPNs for that service and verify that the DNS suffix list is not missing entries. I suspect that Target Principal Name might refer to SPN.

Answer (score 9):

Add this parameter for the connection string: `TrustServerCertificate=true`

Comment: If I add this parameter then it will work will all the certificates which i don't want. i.e If client has any certificate signed by same CA then it will work. I want the client to be able to communicate only if they have proper CA certificate.

Answer (score 1):

When generating DBContext using the Scaffolding, if you are getting the error while connection "provider ssl provider error 0 - the target principal name is incorrect" use this parameter for the connection string: TrustServerCertificate=true

AS the server connection is based on the certificate errors.